# Function evaluating to lambda cannot be used to define new function within scope

Tags: scheme, r5rs

In scheme you can define functions which return a lambda expression and use them to define new functions. For example, you can write this code

```
(define (pow-iter base exp r)
  (if (= exp 1)
      r
      (pow-iter base (- exp 1) (* base r))))

(define (pow exp)
  (lambda (base)
    (pow-iter base exp base)))

(define cubic (pow 3))

(cubic 2)
```

We have here a function `pow` which takes the exponent as argument and evaluates to a lambda function which evaluates to the nth power of the given base.

However, if we put that within a scope like this:

```
(define (do-cubic x)
  (define (pow-iter base exp r)
    (if (= exp 1)
        r
        (pow-iter base (- exp 1) (* base r))))

  (define (pow exp)
    (lambda (base)
      (pow-iter base exp base)))

  (define cubic (pow 3))

  (cubic x))

(do-cubic 2)
```

I get an error

> pow: undefined; cannot use before initialization

Why does this error occur and is there any way to fix it without changing the logic of the program?

Comment: In Racket it works.

Comment: @Renzo You mean that it works in `#!racket`. In `#!r5rs`, even under RacketVM, it should fail. They are different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program provokes the same error:

```
#lang r5rs
(let ()
  (define (foo x) (lambda (y) (+ 42 x)))
  (define bar (foo 1))
  (bar 2))

Output:
  foo: undefined;
  cannot use before initialization
```

The reason you get an error is that "internal definitions" are rewritten into a `letrec` expression all the bindings are in effect while their initial values are being computed, thus allowing mutually recursive definitions.

```
(letrec ((foo (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ 42 x))))
         (bar (foo 1)))
 (bar 2))
```

In R5RS the initialization expressions are evaluated in an *unspecified* order. This means that in the first snippet above it is possible for `(define bar (foo 1))` to be evaluated before `(define (foo x) ...)`. In other words the value of `foo` is needed before `foo` have been initialized.

In Racket (`#lang racket`) internal definitions use `letrec*`-semantics (i.e. the initialization expressions are evaluated in the order they appear in the code. Thus the program runs without errors.

Note also that the `letrec` in `#lang racket` corresponds to what `letrec*` does in "R5RS"-implementations.

For more information on `letrec` vs `letrec*` see the introduction of http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/letrec-reloaded.pdf